# IOS RemoveObserver for Key Value Pair Exception causes extra Retain Count for ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, observers, keyvaluepair

IOS 6.1

We have noticed that when we get an exception for removeObserver for a Key Value Pair that is not there, the class that has the KVP get's and extra retain count from the removeObserver Call.

Following is some test code that proves this.  Also in there is a bridging release that fixes this.

Any comments welcome....

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ClassA.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) ClassA* classA;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"radarOn"])
    {
        NSLog(@"--- here in radaron");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Here" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (IBAction)CreateClassAAction:(id)sender
{
    self.classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)SendNotificationAction:(id)sender
{
    self.classA.radarOn = ! self.classA.radarOn;
}

- (IBAction)ClearKVPAction:(id)sender
{
    @try
    {
        [self.classA removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"radarOn"];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Exception ClassA Retain Count %ld %@", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)(self.classA)), exception.description];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:s delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        // this will let the class release
        // CFBridgingRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(self.classA));
    }
}

- (IBAction)AddKVPAction:(id)sender
{
  [self.classA addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"radarOn" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}

@end
```

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL radarOn;

@end
```

---

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA

- (void) dealloc
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"ClassA Dealloc" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

@end
```

Comment: What is `ClearNotificationsAction` supposed to be doing? You should never call `removeObserver:` on the default notification center from `UIViewController`; you can't guarantee which notifications your superclass might have registered. Since this appears to be ARC enabled, I'm not sure you can use `reatainCount` reliably. Have you used instruments to verify that it's being leaked?

Comment: That was just another test, can ignore for this discussion.  Will remove.  Also of course on instruments, otherwise would not have posted.  The release is to allow the class to release because of the retain count bug.

Comment: Problem solved.  This is an exception / ARC issue, not just a removeObserver issue.  Will detail an answer when I can but, instead of self.classA removeObserver use _classA removeObserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code like this seems to work... (no extra retain)

```
- (IBAction)ClearKVPAction:(id)sender
{
    @try
    {
        [_classA removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"radarOn"];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
    }  
}
```

Or

```
- (IBAction)ClearKVPAction:(id)sender
{
    ClassA* temp = self.classA;
    @try
    {
        [temp removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"radarOn"];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
    }  
}
```

Or

Add -fobjc-arc-exceptions to the .m file(s) in question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a "feature" of ARC [lifted from the Clang 3.4 documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#exceptions):

> Exceptions
>
> By default in Objective C, ARC is not exception-safe for normal
>   releases:
>
> It does not end the lifetime of __strong variables when their scopes
>   are abnormally terminated by an exception. It does not perform
>   releases which would occur at the end of a full-expression if that
>   full-expression throws an exception. A program may be compiled with
>   the option -fobjc-arc-exceptions in order to enable these, or with the
>   option -fno-objc-arc-exceptions to explicitly disable them, with the
>   last such argument “winning”.
>
> Rationale The standard Cocoa convention is that exceptions signal
>   programmer error and are not intended to be recovered from. Making
>   code exceptions-safe by default would impose severe runtime and code
>   size penalties on code that typically does not actually care about
>   exceptions safety. Therefore, ARC-generated code leaks by default on
>   exceptions, which is just fine if the process is going to be
>   immediately terminated anyway. Programs which do care about recovering
>   from exceptions should enable the option. In Objective-C++,
>   -fobjc-arc-exceptions is enabled by default.
>
> Rationale C++ already introduces pervasive exceptions-cleanup code of
>   the sort that ARC introduces. C++ programmers who have not already
>   disabled exceptions are much more likely to actual require
>   exception-safety. ARC does end the lifetimes of __weak objects when an
>   exception terminates their scope unless exceptions are disabled in the
>   compiler.
>
> Rationale The consequence of a local __weak object not being destroyed
>   is very likely to be corruption of the Objective-C runtime, so we want
>   to be safer here. Of course, potentially massive leaks are about as
>   likely to take down the process as this corruption is if the program
>   does try to recover from exceptions.

Comment: Yep, found this eventually.  This is really a strange default setup since exceptions are a very common / normal way of implementation.  I think it is not correct that -fobjc-arc-exceptions are enabled by default, at least not in out app or a test app that is posted.  Once the flag is added, starting problem / leak is "fixed".